# Regex capture for multiple occurrences and place them in groups

Tags: regex, groovy

I have the following line where the string "winline" may occur 1 or more times (or none) and I do not know in advance how many times it would appear in the line.

Is there a way I can capture all 'winline' that occurs in this text? I am using Groovy and tried just matching the winline and it does capture all but each is stated as group 1. I want to be able to capture them group by group.

Example using this regex on following line: winline\":([0-9]+)

```
def matcher
def winningSym = /winline\":([0-9]+)/

if((matcher = line =~ winningSym)){
    println matcher[0][1] // get 5 which is right
    println matcher[1][1] // expect 4 but get IndexOutOfBounds Exception
}
```

**Line:**

> {"Id":1,"winline":5,"Winnings":50000, some random text, "winline":4,
>   more random text, "winline":7, more stuff}

Comment: Is that **really** the text you have to parse?  Someone saw the JSON format, and decided to write their own unparseable variant?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, unfortunately it is the text that needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may slightly modify the regex to use a positive lookbehind and use a simpler code:

```
def winningSym = /(?<=winline":)[0-9]+/
String s = """{"Id":1,"winline":5,"Winnings":50000, some random text, "winline":4, more random text, "winline":7, more stuff}"""
def res = s.findAll(winningSym)
println(res)
```

See the [Groovy demo](http://ideone.com/vs4guK), output: `[5, 4, 7]`.

To use your regex and collect Group 1 values use `.collect` on the matcher (as Matcher supports the *`iterator()`* method):

```
def winningSym = /winline":([0-9]+)/
String line = """{"Id":1,"winline":5,"Winnings":50000, some random text, "winline":4, more random text, "winline":7, more stuff}"""
def res = (line =~ winningSym).collect { it[1] }
```

See [another Groovy demo](http://ideone.com/vanK4v). Here, `it[1]` will access the contents inside capturing group 1 and `.collect` will iterate through all matches.